# Prevent pandas.read_csv from inferring dtypes

Tags: python, pandas

How to prevent `pandas.read_csv()` from inferring the data types. For example, its converting strings `true` and `false` to Bool: `True` and `False`. The columns are many for many files, therefore not feasible to do:

`df['field_name'] = df['field_name'].astype(np.float64)` for each of the columns in each file. I prefer pandas to just read file as it is, no type inferring.

Comment: This isn't really relevant, but *why* would you prefer such a thing?

Comment: This comes in useful if you have values such as Zip Codes which you would not like to be interpreted as numbers, but rather as categories.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the parameter `dtype=object` for Pandas to keep the data as such at load time.